# How do I renew my domain when the registrar no longer exists?

Tags: domain-registration

I have had a domain since the mid '90s, first registered with a UK company which we will call P2.

P2 were then bought by another company appropriately nearly called P1.  They upgraded the control panel facilities and security but otherwise business as usual.

In 2017, unknown to me and with no warning, P1 were dissolved and their domain name acquired by a healthcare provider in the USA.  My domain was passed on to the US company, ENOM who have never contacted me or notified me of the transfer and do not appear to continue the control panel facility or credentials.  At the moment, I have no method of renewing, transferring or updating the domain details.

The domain is about to come up for renewal...

How does a domain come to be transferred out of the country of registration, or become allocated to a foreign registrar in the event of failure of the existing registrar?

What can I do to ensure the domain stays with me?

Comment: Are your contact details / email address for the domain in WHOIS still current?

Comment: Give the domain name involved. The rules depend a lot on the TLD and everyone would be able to see exactly the current situation of your domain.

Comment: Hi Docroot. Yes, the contact details are unchanged.

Comment: Hi Patrick, TLD is .Net

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that you've been with ENOM all along and P1 and P2 were just resellers. Either way, ENOM have a knowledge base article that seems to cover your situation:

https://www.enom.com/kb/kb/kb_247_unresponsive-reseller.htm

> #### Unresponsive Reseller (Who is my Reseller?) - How can I manage my domain?
>
> Article Number: KB 247
>   Product: Domain Management
>
> **Problem**
>   If my reseller is out of business, how can I gain access to my domain? How do I find out where I purchased my domain?
>
> **Solution**
>   If you have a domain that is registered through a Reseller or other Domain Service Provider with eNom, and you would like to gain access to the domain, please follow the below steps:
>
> - Verify that the domain is registered through a particular Reseller: [Lookup Your Provider here](http://www.enom.com/help/reseller_lookup.asp).
> - Attempt to contact the Reseller through the contact information listed. Even if a Reseller is out of business, they may still respond to your request and be able to assist you.
> - Are you listed as the Registrant? Use the [WHOIS Lookup](http://www.enom.com/whois/) to find out. If so, we may be able to help you should your Reseller not respond within 48 hours. Even if your domain is expired, we can help you to renew the domain and get your domain back up and operational.
> - If the Reseller doesn't respond to your request within 48 hours, please create your own account at [www.eNomCentral.com](http://www.enomcentral.com/) and submit a ticket with the following attributes:
>
>   - Subject: "Unresponsive Reseller"
>   - Category: Domain Management
>   - Sub-Category: General Management
>   - Question: [Include the domain name, the dates you contacted the Reseller, and how we can help you].
>
>     > NOTE: Be sure to scan and attach an uncropped color copy of government issued Photo ID that matches the Registrant Contact (such as passport or drivers license).
>
>   This provides validation that you are the owner of the domain.
>
> We'll be happy to work with you to transfer the domain into your own eNomCentral account so that you have full access to manage your domain at any time. This includes renewals, updates to your registrant information, or changes to your hosting records for example. Our Technical Support team are available to assist you 24 hours a day, 7 days a week, every day of the year.

Comment: Thanks for that - I searched but couldn't find - didn't think to try 'unresponsive reseller'!